# Anyway to connect to external databease from GCP ? (From PHP - Laravel app)

Tags: php, database, laravel, google-cloud-platform, external

I want to "use Google Cloud SQL Proxy to connect to another vendors database"

(Vendor's database is not stored in GCP, It's simple mysql database hosted in another server)

---

since I have to update data in vendor's database, my project stored in GCP (hosted separate from vendor's) so:

> Is there anyway to connect to external database from GCP app (Laravel 5) Or any other way to solve it except developing web APIs (vendor won't prepare us the APIs since some contract/budged reasons) ?

After I tried to connect to the external DB (set connection in both .env and config/database.php), then the error message alert like:

```
Access denided @'cloudsqlproxy'
```

*PS. My project can connect to vendor's database as usual from localhost but after deploy to GCP then 'cloudsqlproxy' error's occur.*

I'm a newbie one for GCP so 
thank you for all community's help,

Comment: I'm not sure if Google Cloud Platform has anything special regarding databases, but in general terms you can access the database from anywhere as long as you grant it access. This usually means getting the right credentials and opening up access from specific IP address (e.g. the server you're connecting to the database from)

Comment: Your question needs specific details. Are you trying to use Google Cloud SQL Proxy to connect to another vendors database? Edit your question with your code, details on the configuration and error messages.

Comment: Yes, 

I want to "use Google Cloud SQL Proxy to connect to another vendors database"